# "404 not found" when trying to make calls to a GRPC server (on GKE) from web client (grpc-web)

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc-web

so I've deployed a GRPC service to GKE and **confirmed it works by connecting and making calls in python**... but my goal is to create a front end web app rather than just use python.

So I have a simple React app that uses grpc-web to connect, but I'm getting a  "404 (Not Found)" error when making ANY api calls.

[Here is the yaml file I'm using to deploy the service.](https://github.com/OlamAI/Proto/blob/add-model-bases/simulation/grpc-simulation.yaml)

At first I was getting CORS errors but fixed that by adding lines 48-52 and creating a new service that serves HTTP1.

What might be causing a 404 error?

Comment: What's your grpc-web connection url?

Comment: the IP of the LoadBalancer I'm connecting to from grpc-web?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `protocol: TCP` to `protocol: HTTP` in any of your service `LoadBalancer` definitions? May be an issue with using Layer 4 vs Layer 7?

Comment: @PAckerman just tried that but it doesn't look like HTTP is a valid protocol, only TCP or UDP

Comment: It's valid according to Kubernetes docs but maybe not for GKE. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#protocol-support
Only other thought is to try an Ingress.

Comment: Otherwise you may need a service mesh like Envoy or Linkerd.

Comment: @PAckerman I really appreciate your help man, you have no idea how stuck on this I've been! I'm actually using an [Envoy proxy for local dev](https://gist.github.com/diericx/d9294f2e95e53ed17f89c8119c899113), but I'm confused on how to create a similar proxy for production. Can I still use 0.0.0.0 as the addresses or should I change those to 127.0.0.1? In the "clusters" section, does the "name" field need to match my service name in K8s? Would "host.docker.internal" still work?

Comment: I think 0.0.0.0 may still work. Check out this: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/envoy-flask-google-container-engine
Specifically the section on setting up edge Envoy. It's not specific for GRPC (its for a flask app), but the principle should be the same.

Answer (score -1):

For gRPC-Web to work, you need to have an Envoy endpoint in front of your gRPC service. In particular, you need to enable the gRPC-Web filter on your `envoy.yaml` config like this: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/blob/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/echo/envoy.yaml#L35-L38

Comment: You referenced the `master` branch and now nobody will ever now which code you meant… A permalink is better for next time :)